# Context menu gets clipped on the right side

Tags: javafx-8

I show a context menu on right click but for every second click the right side of the menu gets clipped (about 1 to 2 character width) The basics that I can put here:

```
void initialise(Handler eventHandler) {
    addMenuItem(eventHandler, "New", new NewAction(shell),false);
    addMenuItem(eventHandler, "Edit", new EditAction(shell),false);
    menuItems.add(new SeparatorMenuItem());
    ... more items
}

void addMenuItem(Handler eventHandler, String text, Action action, boolean isCheck) {   
    actions.add(action);
    MenuItem it = isCheck ? new CheckMenuItem() : new MenuItem();
    it.setText(text);
    it.setData(action);
    it.setDisable(true);
    menuItems.add(it);
}

    ....
    menu = new ContextMenu();
    menu.getItems().clear();
    menu.getItems().addAll(getMenuItems(getSelection()));
    menu.setAutoHide(true);
    ...
```

What I've figured out is that it happens on every second right click and although the menu occupy the same rectangle, the drawn part is shifted by 12 pixels, giving the appearance that it's been clipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the effect style to null in the code or the css file